# Windows 10 start menu problems

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

My start menu has stopped working, I can't right-click on taskbar items (does nothing) and the volume button doesn't work (I right-click to go to volume mixer)

How do I resolve this?

Comment: have you restartet the Shell (Explorer.exe) as admin? here the new apps (start is also an app) no longer work.

Comment: actually yeah i did and to no avail....

Comment: **BUMP** trying to update using setup file on windows 10 image

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "setup file on win10 image"

Comment: I had an iso , i mounted it ; used the setup.exe on it , updating : update : stuck at 16% searching for updates

Comment: disconnect from the Internet before running setup

Answer (score 0):

I had that happen a couple of days ago, I hit ctrl-alt-del and told it to restart... and it started to, but never completed.
Hard reset and chkdsk after that, seems to be working normally now.

Comment: what do u mean by hard-reset?

Comment: Power off the computer, power it back on.

Comment: Good answer ; but this prob has been there for a month that means ; i have done it a thousand times ; chkdsk'ed a lotta times

Comment: Have you added any new software that adds [or should] an entry to the context menu? (r-click) I've seen that mess up explorer in the same fashion on win 7, but killing explorer.exe always fixed it.

Comment: None that i remember of ; currently using startmenux becuz start doesnt work ( uninstalling it results nothing)

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do in this case, like changing the settings of the start menu, and installing updates.

You can find here steps you can take:
https://win10faq.com/windows-10-start-menu-not-working/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time a simple restart will do the job. if not you could have a driver problem. specially using win xp

Comment: i actually feel very dumb installing win 10 over 8 (fresh-install) and as of a restart ; i have done it a million times